# how to add a shared commandbar in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Hello I am making my first official Windows Phone 8.1 app. I was wondering how do I add a shared command bar across my entire app. The way I have been doing it is copy and pasting the xaml from each page to the next. I have a feeling this is very inefficient I just don't know how to do it and where to add it(as in what page).
thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `CommandBar` to the resources of `Application` (in App.xaml). Then you can simply set it from the resource on each page:

```
<Application.Resources>
  <CommandBar x:Key="GlobalCommandBar"/>
</Application.Resources>

<Page
  x:Class="..."
  BottomAppBar={StaticResource GlobalCommandBar}>
</Page>
```

Comment: As far as I've tested it's not possible to put command bar into resources.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways that come to my mind:

a) first is to do it like [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150604.aspx) - basicly you extend the *Page* class and in *OnLoaded* ecent add application bar on the fly. Then change all your pages in the app to the extended one.

b) other method is little more complicated (as far as I remember I saw it also somewhere at MSDN) and needs more steps, but maybe will be helpful:

- you will need to change what is in your *Window.Current.Content* - in most apps it's *Frame*, let's make it *Page* with our common application bar and this Page content will be our new rootFrame (all app pages will be put into that frame). Here we will need to change a little *OnLaunched* event, below the code for extended page and the launch event:

  ```xml
  <Page x:Class="Example81.PageWithAppBar"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

        <Frame Name="rootFrame"></Frame>

        <Page.BottomAppBar>
           <CommandBar>
             <AppBarButton Icon="Help" Label="Ask"/>
           </CommandBar>
        </Page.BottomAppBar>
  </Page>
  ```

  ```cs
  // we need to expose the frame
  public sealed partial class PageWithAppBar : Page
  {
      public Frame RootFrame { get { return rootFrame; } }
      // rest ...
  ```

  ```cs
  // app.xam.cs launched event
  PageWithAppBar rootPage;
  public CommandBar MyAppBar { get { return rootPage.BottomAppBar as CommandBar; } }
  protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
  {
      rootPage = Window.Current.Content as PageWithAppBar;
      if (rootPage == null)
      {
          rootPage = new PageWithAppBar();

          rootPage.Language = Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.Languages[0];
          Window.Current.Content = rootPage;
      }
      if (rootPage.RootFrame.Content == null)
          rootPage.RootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);

      Window.Current.Activate();
  }
  ```
- we also shouldn't forget about other things - like back key pressed, we changed a little our app organization, so this will also change:

  ```cs
  private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
  {
      Frame frame = rootPage.RootFrame;
      if (frame == null)
          return;

      if (frame.CanGoBack)
      {
          frame.GoBack();
          e.Handled = true;
      }
  }
  ```
- then you can normaly navigate in your other pages, to access your app bar I've exposed above a property in App class, you can use it like this:

  ```cs
  ((App.Current as App).MyAppBar.PrimaryCommands[0] as AppBarButton).Label = "New label";
  ```

The second way is little more complicated, also it needs some more improvement and probably some changes in *NavigationHelper* and *SuspensionManager*. A working sample with the code above you can [find at GitHub](https://github.com/Romasz/WP81RunTime-Examples/tree/master/CommonAppBar).